# converting with the same quality

Tags: ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -i cam2.DAT -qscale:v cam2.avi`
When run, this returns "At least one output file must be specified", what am I missing?
Probably, there is another method to convert with the same quality?

Comment: You need to specify a value for qscale, so `ffmpeg -i cam2.DAT -qscale:v 7 cam2.avi`

Comment: Yes, I already found this solution. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

As said user:5726027 there must be a number [description for value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz9RR.png)
Finally `ffmpeg -i cam2.DAT -qscale:v 7 cam2.avi` worked

Comment: This will not make "same quality" because you are using a lossy encoder. If the codecs are suitable you can re-mux: `ffmpeg -i input -c copy output`.